# Change Color of Td Based on Value of td

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to change the color of the table td to red when the days elapsed is over 10 days. I tried to do it with jQuery but i failed. I only want to check the td's with the class `.elapsed` and the tables id is table.
However my code is not working properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#table td").each(function () {
            if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 10) {
                $(this).parent("tr").css("background-color", "red");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select `"#table td"` targets all the `td`s in the table. To target only the `td`s with class `elapsed`, you can narrow down your selector to this:

```
"#table td.elapsed"
```

So the following should work as per your requirements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table td.elapsed").each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 10) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

Also, I've changed `$(this).parent("tr").css` to `$(this).css`, so that the background of `td` changes.